# MySQL count rows of multiple tables for each user

Tags: mysql, select, php, count

I basically need [this](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/97180/mysql-count-rows-from-another-table-for-each-record-in-table) with some adjustments, I just can't seem to figure it out how to do it.
I need to sum the rows of two tables, for example:

```
SELECT
  student.StudentID,
  student.`Name`,
  COUNT(attendance.AttendanceID) AS Total
FROM
  student
LEFT JOIN attendance ON student.StudentID = attendance.StudentID
GROUP BY student.StudentID,student.`Name\`;
```

This would return

```
+-----------+-------------------+-------+
| StudentID | Name              | Total |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+
| k1052280  | Ali Shaikh        |     2 |
| k1052287  | McKenzie Roth     |     2 |
| k1052288  | Dacey Sullivan    |     1 |
| k1052294  | Zelda Cantu       |     0 |
| k1052295  | Kimberly Melton   |     3 |
| k1052296  | Tatianna Cantrell |     0 |
| k1052297  | Morgan Thornton   |     0 |
| k1052298  | Allistair Barlow  |     0 |
| k1052299  | Troy Fulton       |     0 |
+-----------+-------------------+-------+
```

Total being the rows for the attendance table/student. I need to add in another table, for example meetings, i need a SUM of the two, so the total should be the sum of meetings + attendances for each student.

Comment: Calculate `(StudentID, COUNT(AttendanceID))` in subquery. Do the same with `meetings`. Join these 2 subqueries to `student` table and obtain/calculate the result you need.